# Upgrading Custom Sitecore Solr SearchProvider

Tags: solr

I am in process of upgrading Sitecore from 8.2 to 10 and also Solr.

SolrSearchWithSpatialContext was implemented by previous team but looks like this code is outdated now and there has been no update.

https://github.com/ehabelgindy/sitecore-solr-spatial/blob/master/Source/Sitecore.ContentSearch.Spatial.Solr/Provider/SolrSearchWithSpatialContext.cs

Basically this class is inherited from `SolrSearchContext`.

```
        public SolrSearchWithSpatialContext(SolrSearchIndex index,
            SearchSecurityOptions options = SearchSecurityOptions.EnableSecurityCheck)
            : base(index, index.Locator.GetInstance<ILinqToIndexFactory>() , options)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(index, "index");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(options, "options");
            _contentSearchSettings = index.Locator.GetInstance<IContentSearchConfigurationSettings>();
        }
```

In the new version, an additional parameter,`ILinqToIndexFactory` ,has been introduced for instantiating `SolrSearchContext`

I am not able to figure out how to resolve this parameter. I tried few different things but no success and there is hardly any documentation available around this.

I tried passing `index.Locator.GetInstance<ILinqToIndexFactory>()` but then it throws exception saying `Service Sitecore.ContentSearch.Abstractions.Factories.ILinqToIndexFactory was not registered in container`

Please if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spatial search is supported by Sitecore out-of-the-box starting from version 9.0 so no additional modules or custom providers are required. See documentation about Sitecore spatial search [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/using-solr-spatial-search.html).

You can remove all code related to the custom search context and instead use standard search functionality on your upgraded Sitecore 10 website. For example, this is how radius search can be implemented:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext())
{
       var queryable = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
       .WithinRadius (s => s.Location, new Coordinate (lat, lng), radius);           
       var results = queryable.ToList();
}
```